# Django and DRF, ip limit for request

Tags: django-rest-framework, throttling

I need an advise

I have some public endpoint created using DRF. Now I want to limit access to it: for example no more than 5 requests in a day.

What library/module should I use? Or is there anything in DRF itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we have a concept named "Throttling" in django rest framework. Throttles indicate a temporary state, and are used to control the rate of requests that clients can make to an API.

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/